# How to return images from Parse within defined radius using GeoPoint

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-location

I am building an app which returns images from `Parse` cloud with `GeoPoint` based on the users current `location`.

I need help with how can I get the user's current location and based on their defined radius I can query for the images from `Parse` Cloud.

```
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<PlaceFilter>();
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "geo_filters");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending

            for (ParseObject PlaceName : ob) {
                // Locate images in flag column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) PlaceName.get("FilterFile");

                PlaceFilter map = new PlaceFilter();
                map.setPlaceName((String) PlaceName.get("PlaceName"));
                map.setFilterFile(image.getUrl());
                worldpopulationlist.add(map);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with passions

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("ImageClassName");
                    Location location = getLastKnownLocation(); //You have to get last known location using LOcationManager or FusedLocation API
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
        parseQuery.whereNear("location", userLocation); //column as location
        parseQuery.whereWithinKilometers("location", userLocation, 5);
        parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> listImages,
                    ParseException arg1) {
                for(image : listImages){
                    ParseFile parseFile = image.getParseFile("imageColumn");
                        if (parseFile != null) {
                            parseFile.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    if (data != null && e == null) {
                                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                                .decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                                        data.length);
                                        myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    } else {
                                        /picture_not_available
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
//                                picture_not_available
                        }
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: How do I get the location from the user? Do i have use google.gms.location ? I would also like to know where should i include the above code in my MainActivity